# How to align separated equations in LaTeX?

Tags: latex, alignment

I can use the align environment to properly align non-separated equations like this:

```
begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^2\\
          &= d
\end{align}
```

but how can I align separated equations with text inbetween? For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

My first equation:

\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{equation}

My second equation:

\begin{equation}
1 = 3 - 2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I would like the two equations to be aligned at the equality sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place both equations in an `align` environment and add the text in between with `\intertext{...}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

My first equation:

\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= c^2\\     
\intertext{My second equation:}
          &= d
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, it seems `\shortintertext` (from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) seems equally appropriate.